# JPA / Get list of entities as references

Tags: java, jpa, java-ee-6, criteria, jpql

The EntityManager provides a method getReference().

Is there something similar in JPQL or event better within CriteriaBuilder, that would return a list of entities just as references?

Actual I use just the ID and process each entity in a new transaction. I want to avoid the get all entities, because it would mess up my memory usage.

If I could use references, I would be type safe and the memory overhead would be okay.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answers how to get the ID. I had something similar to `getReference()` in mind. There you get an entity not only the ID of the entity. For sure, these reference entities contain only the ID, but still, I've a dedicated class instead of `Long`. I guess, there is nothing similar to `getReference()` to get a list of references

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something like

```
select idField from YourEntity where ..
```

and similarly in your criteria query, just use the `YourEntity.idField_` value.

Answer (score 0):

to ensure type-safety in criteria case, you can do this:

```
CriteriaQuery<Long> criteria =criteriaBuilder.createQuery(entityClass);
Root<T> r=criteria.from(entityClass);

//Where clauses

criteria.select(r.<Long>get("id"));

TypedQuery<Long> query=entityManager.createQuery(criteria);
List<Long> result=query.getResultList();
```